# How can I preserve the CSS of a Gist?

Tags: css, github, gist

On a blog post on my website, I decided to share some of my code using a GitHub Gist, since I thought it would be an easy way to apply code formatting and syntax highlighting to my code.

I've embedded the Gist in the post, but for some reason my website's CSS has overridden the CSS of the Gist and so I've ended up with code which is all grey and in a serif font. I assumed that since the stylesheet in the Gist is being linked to after my main stylesheet link, it would be fine, but this seems not to be the case.

How can I make it so that my main stylesheet won't modify the styling of the Gist?

Edit: [Here](http://seanduffy.co.uk/blog/2013/6/Project_-Lights-Out/) is the page where the problem is occurring, the Gist is near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the embed option? There would be one located on the left sidebar the says "embed this gist" which uses different ids from your css stylesheet so it wont conflict.

You can also rename your selectors on your website, the second stylesheet takes priority not the first.

Comment: That's what I thought, for some reason the styles of the Gist are the ones that I have applied to the body of my website, but shouldn't the stylesheet of the Gist override those since it is the second to be linked?

Comment: You should post a sample of it so we can inspect it to see what is actually going on.

Comment: I have added a link to my post. Apologies, at first I accidentally clicked the button to edit your post instead of mine.

Comment: Get rid of #post span and change it to span

Comment: This seems to have fixed the colours, but the font family and size is still being overwritten.

Comment: Span is still overwriting it, you might just have to get rid of it completely and target the selector you want to put span in.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now, instead of using span I've changed that style to just us an id and it works fine.